# Retrofit Android: How to convert array to POJO in a good way?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

My question is:  How to plugin in GSON convert (or other things) so that the out put of the API is directly `List<Student>`.

Currently I am doing this outside of the API call myself, which I think is kind of bad code:

```
for (List<String> eachData : data) {
            result.add(new Student(eachData.get(1), Integer.valueOf(eachData.get(2))));
}
```

---

Json Response (NOTE: each student is an array, not object)

```
{
   "data":[
      [
         1,
         "Tom",
         18,
         "USA"
      ],
      [
         2,
         "Linda",
         21,
         "Mexico"
      ]
   ],
   "other":[
      "100",
      "400"
   ]
}
```

StudentsApi.java

```
@GET("/api/test.json")
Observable<GetStudentsResponse> getStudents();
```

GetStudentsResponse.java

```
public class GetStudentsResponse {
    public List<List<String>> data;  // PROBABLY NEED TO CHANGE HERE?
}
```

If I do the follow, I got the error **`expected begin_object but was begin_array retrofit`**.

```
public class GetStudentsResponse {
    public List<Student> data;
}
```

Student.java

```
class Student {
  int age;
  String name;
  // what do I do here?  How can I map the array to object?
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to/can't just work with `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` ?

Comment: First, create your POJO class using below link and see what is output need.
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: You should have a look to [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson "Gson")

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How can I use it and how do I map to a POJO?

Comment: @VishalPatolia I will need List<List<String>> data;.  But do I then just manually recreate each Student with List<String>?  Can I plug in a GSON convert somehow so the code looks better?

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON means that it starts with an Object, then have a JSONArray with name **data** which includes another **JSONArray** with generic types (String, Integers).
It also includes another **JSONArray** called **other** including Strings in your Sample. That means:

```
@GET("/api/test.json")
Observable<GetStudentsResponse> getStudents();
```

would work if you use

```
public List<List<Object>> data;  
public List<String> other;
```

Just used Unit-Test and works.

```
@Test
public void testGsonSerialize() {
    String jsonArr = "{\"data\":[[1,\"Tom\",18,\"USA\"],[2,\"Linda\",21,\"Mexico\"]],\"other\":[\"100\",\"400\"]}";
    GetStudentsResponse getStudentsResponse =  new Gson().fromJson(jsonArr, GetStudentsResponse.class);
    Assert.assertTrue(getStudentsResponse.data.size() > 0);
    Assert.assertTrue(getStudentsResponse.other.size() > 0);
}
```

Make sure that if your "other" doesnt contain only Strings that you Type it as Object instead of else it will Throw you a Cast or Parse Exception (not sure what Gson uses)

Comment: Currently, I am get a 'List<List<Object>>' myself and recreating a 'List<Student>' in an array myself.  How can I use GSON and plugin to retrofit so that the output is 'List<Student>' directly out of the API.  This way, the code looks better.

Comment: For this case you need to unwrap your JSONObject and format the output using a JSON Deserializer. Take a look at GSONs JsonDeserializer class. You can do lot of evil and good stuff creating your own deserializer

Comment: So the problem comes down to:  how to use GSON to deserialize an array to a POJO and use it with Android Retrofit?  am I understand it right?